# if (MageCustomer.name !== undefined) { Getting Error Null

Tags: javascript, magento-1.9

I have a simple menu and want to show login else account links.

I am sure I had this working but after some changes to js files it is no longer working.

I know its going to be something simple but can't figure it out.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( MageCustomer.name !== undefined ) {
        $( '.mm-account' ).removeClass( 'hide' ).find( '.name' ).text( MageCustomer.name );
    } else {
        $( '.mm-login' ).removeClass( 'hide' );
    }
</script>
<ul>
    <li class="mm-login hide"><a href="{{config path=" web/unsecure/base_url "}}customer/account/login">Login/Join</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mm-account hide"><a href="{{config path=" web/unsecure/base_url "}}customer/account">My Account (<span class="name green"></span>)</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mm-account hide"><a href="{{config path=" web/unsecure/base_url "}}customer/account/logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{config path=" web/unsecure/base_url "}}ordering-information">Ordering Information</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{config path=" web/unsecure/base_url "}}shipping-options">Delivery Info</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{config path=" web/unsecure/base_url "}}terms-and-conditions">Free Returns</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{config path=" web/unsecure/base_url "}}contacts">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{config path=" web/unsecure/base_url "}}faq">FAQ</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Error in console is this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of null at eval (eval at
<anonymous> (prototype.js?v=1.0.19:612),
    <anonymous>:5:15) at prototype.js?v=1.0.19:612 at prototype.js?v=1.0.19:865 at prototype.js?v=1.0.19:825 at Array.forEach (
        <anonymous>) at Array.each (prototype.js?v=1.0.19:824) at Array.collect (prototype.js?v=1.0.19:864) at String.evalScripts (prototype.js?v=1.0.19:612) at Function.
            <anonymous> (prototype.js?v=1.0.19:391) at prototype.js?v=1.0.19:416
```

Comment: Put the javascript code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, Or move it below the HTML

Comment: now says:prototype.js?v=1.0.19:36 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function

Comment: This now does not get error but nothing also happens.
`<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

  if ( MageCustomer.name !== undefined ) {
   jQuery( '.mm-account' ).removeClass( 'hide' ).find( '.name' ).text( MageCustomer.name );
  } else {
   jQuery( '.mm-login' ).removeClass( 'hide' );
  }
 
});
</script>`